Implementing a generic footer previewRenderer in TYPO3 >= v12
We have been using the hook tt_content_drawFooter to add additional information in the page layout view in the Backend for some content elements.
Some of the information would always be displayed, for example it shows information about the 18n_parent content element. Some of the information is specific to content elements such as textmedia.
Now, when upgrading to v12, the hook is dropped. There are some replacement events (but not for the footer) and it is possible to override the previewRenderer, e.g. for all types or for specific content types.
The implementation looks straightforward, but I ran into a problem:

I can use PageContentPreviewRenderingEvent->setPreviewContent() to override the content (but not the footer)
the only way I see to set the footer is by setting the previewRenderer in TCA and then inheriting from the class which was set previously. But for various CE, these will be different classes

For example, this is the default:
general:
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['ctrl']['previewRenderer'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Preview\StandardContentPreviewRenderer::class;

textmedia:
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types'][$ctype]['previewRenderer'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Preview\TextmediaPreviewRenderer;

container content types:
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types'][$ctype]['previewRenderer'] = B13\Container\Backend\Preview\ContainerPreviewRenderer;

news_pi1:
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['news_pi1']['previewRenderer'] = GeorgRinger\News\Hooks\PluginPreviewRenderer;

So if I set my PreviewRenderer, it would have to be a different class inheriting from a different PreviewRender for each one I want to override.
What am I missing? Is this not possible or what would be a good solution?
Example:

Documentation

PageContentPreviewRenderingEvent
Changelog v10: Feature: #78450 - Introduce PreviewRenderer pattern
Changelog v12: Breaking: #98375 - Removed hooks in Page Module

For context, this is the patch where the previous footer hook was removed:

https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/75778


Just an evening thought without deep research: in the partial ../PageLayout/RecordDefault/Footer.html only item.footerInfo is displayed. The partial could easily be overwritten in the meantime (https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.0/Feature-96812-OverrideBackendTemplatesWithTSconfig.html). Then only {item} would have to be suitably enriched with the desired footerContent...

Shall the solution be related to a backend_layout / colPos, a container-element or a single content element? I think it might be important to know, or an important decision.

David, I have these 2 cases: there is some information which should be displayed, regardless of content element (such as the language information). And there is some information which depends on the content element.

I would say you have some options:
Option 1:
You could XClass the StandardContentPreviewRenderer. But this would only work for ctypes that directly uses the StandardContentPreviewRenderer. You would then also have to XClass all specific PreviewRenderers. So that's maybe no good solution.
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html
Option 2:
Implement custom PreviewRenderer for all ctypes you want to manipulate. You could then use a trait to implement your modification. Then you still would need multiple PreviewRenderer, but you could implement your custom code once in the trait.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.traits.php 
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/CodingGuidelines/PhpArchitecture/Traits.html
Option 3:
You could patch your TYPO3 versions StandardContentPreviewRenderer and either implement your code directly in the patch or dispatch your own PSR-14 Event.
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Events/EventDispatcher/Index.html 
https://typo3worx.eu/2017/08/patch-typo3-using-composer/
I think all three solutions comes with some (dis-)advantages.
I would tend towards option 2 as I think it is the most stable solution.
EDIT:
I just tested the option Julian Hofmann mentioned above. Yes you could override the footer partial, but then would need to implement an own ViewHelper to manipulate the footer.
This would work, but i would not prefer. But that's just a personal preference.

Presenting another option based on Julian Hoffmann's comment:
This works for TYPO3 v12 and above.

Use TSconfig to override the Fluid partial
# Pattern: templates."composer-name"."something-unique" = "overriding-extension-composer-name":"entry-path"
templates.typo3/cms-backend.9999999999 = myvendor/myextension:Resources/Private/Backend/TemplateOverrides/typo3/cms-backend


Add the Fluid file to your extension:
Resources/Private/Backend/TemplateOverrides/typo3/cms-backend/Partials/Page-Layout/RecordDefault/Footer.html:
The original looks like this:
<f:if condition="{item.footerInfo}">
  <div class="t3-page-ce-footer">
    <div class="t3-page-ce-info">
      {item.footerInfo -> f:format.raw()}             
    </div>
 </div>
</f:if>

We can add more:
<f:if condition="{item.record.layout}">
  <strong>Layout:</strong>
    <f:translate key="LLL:EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_backend.xlf:tt_content.layout.{item.record.layout}">{item.record.layout}</f:translate>
   <br/>
 </f:if>



Documentation:

v12 Changelog: Feature: #96812 - Override backend templates with TSconfig

